# Prevent users to click RadioButton

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In my form I have some TextBoxes. Once the value of TextBox is changed then corresponding RadioButton will be selected. But I want to prevent users from changing the value of RadioButton. 
I tried disabling like this.

```
 optA.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
```

But this script greys out the radiobutton which is not looking good. Is there any script to prevent users from clicking/changing the selected value of radiobutton?

Small example is

```
totalval=document.getElementById('txt1').value+document.getElementById('txt2').value
if (totalval>101)
document.getElementById('optA1').checked=true;
else if(totalval<100)
document.getElementById('optA2').checked=true;
```

This is what I want. So the users should not change the value of radiobuttons (optA1,optA2)
if am using

```
optA1.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
```

I couldnt get the value of optA1 at server side.
My aspx code is

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="optA1" GroupName="optAchieve" runat="server" Text="30" value="30" onclick="indicateColor()" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="optA2" GroupName="optAchieve" runat="server" Text="20" value="20" onclick="indicateColor()" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to right javascript on radio button click , no matter what the radio option is selected always select the default option from javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Try to prevent user action by onclick event like this :

```
optA.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return false;");
```

Comment: `optA.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return false;");`
This one is working. Onchange of txt1 the `txt1.value` will be assigned to `optA.checked=true`. But if I click radiobutton after setting checked=true the radiobutton goes to unchecked.
And the readonly attribute is not working. I can change the radiobutton's value.

Comment: Actually I don't get what you're doing. Do you check the rendered source by View Source ? maybe you're missing something at your code behind ?

Comment: You're right, readonly is not visually working for checkbox and radiobox.

Comment: Better use a jQuery class selector so that you can make it generic for all the controls. You need not to write same code again and again. Just associate class and avoid redundant code.

Answer (score 1):

Attach a readonly class and change attribute of radio button to unchecked on each click.

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" class="readonlyradio">
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" class="readonlyradio">​
```

Use this function in your JS:

```
  $(".readonlyradio").click(function(){
$(this).attr('checked', false);
  });​
```

Check this fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/Xwtvp/

Hope it helps.